# Login in to google account through an app

Tags: javascript, xml, api

I want to create an application that would allow the user to login to Google without going to the Google page. Is there some guidelines on how to do this?

Comment: For installed applications, have a look at **[Google's documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html)**.

If you want to use this feature for authentication on your website, consider using [OpenID](http://openid.net).

Answer (score 0):

No. The whole point of logging in with google is that google does the authenticating. Your users must actually log in at google.

Now, if these are returning users, and they check the box to remain signed in, then the authentication is invisible.  When they hit the google page they just get redirected right back to your site.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. But I wanted to create a login form that would just send the parameters(username, password) then the google will do the authenticating. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Single sign-on is NOW available for Google apps. see http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224